# Any java example solutions on Reader Writer concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there any good/great java example solutions on [Reader Writer concurrency problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem) that you can recommend, or you can write and paste here?

I am particularly interested in the part "sections protected by counter_mutex could be replaced by a suitable fetch-and-add atomic instruction" (I guess it means `AtomicInteger` objects) on this wiki page.

Comment: "Java Concurrency in Practice" is by far the best book about the subject in Java.

Comment: @toto2, I do not find many good examples in this book, particularly on this reader-writer topic, not even to mention using fetch-and-add atomic instruction to implement the solutions.

Comment: OK, that's possible.  They don't go in much detail on the low-level stuff: they recommend not touching low-level and sticking with the higher-level utilities in java.util.concurrent.  I don't know if you are looking at this problem just for fun, but if you are trying to solve a real problem, you probably also want to stick to higher level constructs.  It's easier to code and also it's better for maintainability (future developers going over the code).

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be what you had in mind, but the implementation of a read-write lock provided by OpenJDK may be [informative](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.java#ReentrantReadWriteLock)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question entirely.
There is a [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) interface with some implementations in the JDK which you can use to solve the reader-writer problem:

> A ReadWriteLock maintains a pair of associated locks, one for
>   read-only operations and one for writing. The read lock may be held
>   simultaneously by multiple reader threads, so long as there are no
>   writers. The write lock is exclusive.

Here is a [problem where I used the read write lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487148/java-concurrency-improving-a-copy-on-read-collection).

Comment: i am more interested in using AtomicInteger to solve reader-writer problem. Do you know any more info?

Comment: @QiangLi I think the ReentrantReadWriteLock used in that answer uses a CAS operation to implement the read/write locks using Sun's Unsafe class similar to how an atomic variable would be used. You might want to check the source code for ReentrantReadWriteLock.